# how to change row value Postgresql following above row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query result like this

```
id | code | data
1  | b001 | 12
1  | b001 | 13
1  | b001 | 15
2  | b002 | 20
2  | b002 | 15
2  | b002 | 10
```

i want to change the data value into 12 and 20 for every different id like this :

```
id | code | data
1  | b001 | 12
1  | b001 | 12
1  | b001 | 12
2  | b002 | 20
2  | b002 | 20
2  | b002 | 20
```

Comment: How do you chose those values? 12 is the min for id 1 but 20 is the max for id 2...

Comment: the first accured by not mentionned order by column I suppose :)

Comment: the first row for every id

Comment: @MichaelVinci first order by what colum?..

Comment: @VaoTsun  i want the data to only show the value for every first data value for each id, so the following column data value will follow the first for each id

Comment: @MichaelVinci "first", "following": these imply some ordering, but you don't have any (at least in the columns you already shown to us) -- PostgreSQL doesn't have an "insertion order" either. You either add a column, which represents that, or you can't order your result set (at least not in a stable way).

Comment: you can order by ctid (tupple id), but results will change from run to run, because ctid changes

Comment: The data in a table is not ordered. The record with data = 12 is not before or after the record with data = 13, they are just somewhere in the table. So you need some criteria to tell why you consider the record with data = 12 to be before the one with data = 13. *Or* you say, order doesn't matter, so the records with ID = 1 would all get either 12 or 13 or 15, only that all get the *same*  value no matter which.

Comment: By the way: The table design looks bad, but that may be just your sample data copied and pasted. All records with ID 1 have code = 'b001'. Can they have different codes? Then the table design is okay. Or must it always be the same code for the same ID? Then have a separate table holding the code with each ID occurring just once.

Comment: @VaoTsun i dont get it using ctid

Comment: @pozs cant i get it without adding another column?

Comment: @OtoShavadze the first row shown on the result from query but the following row  column data after the first row for every id must be the same as the first one

Comment: @MichaelVinci no, you can't. without `ORDER BY`, the SQL engine will give you results in an arbitary order, which can (and will) vary over time, query-by-query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner well this is just the simple version actually and i dont think we need to bother with the id actually its not even id its some kind of complex code with character varying. Like what you said in the comment the order not important it can be 12 or 13 or 15 but the following row for each id must be the same with the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`first_value` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-window.html)

Add this to your `SELECT`:

```
(first_value(data) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) as data
```

Comment: @AlexM its actually work thanks Alex and everyone for the effort